# Is "dentibus" ablative in "Lupus collum ovis petit dentibus..."

Tags: grammar-identification, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

In Cap. IX of LLPSI Pars I, Ørberg tells the story of a black sheep wandering into the forest where it's confronted by a wolf. The wolf finds the sheep alone in the darkness of the forest, and the sheep closes its eyes and waits for the wolf to attack. The sentence *Lupus collum ovis petit dentibus...* then follows. I took this to mean *the wolf makes for the neck of the sheep with its teeth*, or more literally *the wolf makes for the sheep's neck with teeth*.

Is *dentibus* ablative and is the preposition implied, or is this dative and the indirect object of the sentence?

Comment: If it helps, you can often think of the ablative as translated with the suffix -wise in English. In this example: The wolf makes for the sheep's neck teeth-wise. In English too, then, there is no further need for a preposition.

Answer (score 7):

It's an *ablativus instrumentalis*, or an instrumental ablative, and specifically an [ablative of means](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/ablative-means). No preposition necessary or even permitted.

Answer (score 7):

It's ablative.

There's no preposition because this is the *instrumental* use of the ablative. [@TKR](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/40/tkr) helped me out with this [long ago](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/1435/118) when he pointed out that you would not say *cum* to indicate *using* the teeth to attack. This meaning is indicated by the plain ablative with no preposition (with a non-human noun).

I'm glad I'm not the only one who finds the [dative-ablative ambiguity](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4485/118) puzzling! The answer to that question points out that this is seldom a problem in practice; and I'm happy to say that as I've gotten more experience with Latin, there seems to be less and less ambiguity between ablative and dative. In the case of the *lupus,* you guessed right: the wolf attacks the sheep with its (the wolf's) teeth, of course—since that makes sense.

Another clue is that the verb *peto* doesn't have much use for a dative noun. I'm having a hard time thinking of how to use a dative noun with *peto;* maybe *Canis ovi lupum petivit:* "The dog attacked the wolf on behalf of the sheep."

Comment: What if you were saying something like "the wolf, with the dog, attacked the sheep"? I'd imagine it's more straight forward to just keep _wolf_ and _dog_ nominative and use _et_ and a plural verb, but if you wanted to make it clearer that the wolf is the main aggressor it might make sense to word it this way (at least in English): _lupus collum ovis petit cum cane_. I'm not sure if that requires a plural verb, though.

Comment: I have seen _cum_ used instead of _et_ many times to set up a singular verb, just as you illustrate (or, more prosaically, _lupus cum cane ovem petit_), but [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=c4sAAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA204&ots=oBuspdi7c1&dq=latin%20cum%20et%20singular&pg=PA204#v=onepage&q=%22more%20frequently%20a%20plural%20verb%22&f=false) suggests the plural. I'm no expert, but I've come to think of that use of _cum_ as a Latin mannerism.

Comment: @Adam You can use **cum** as well as **et** for this; the verb can be either singular or plural according to how much of a single idea the two subjects form in your head. For maximum disambiguation you have **ūnā cum** "together with". Notice though that postponing *cum cane* so far from the subject is quite awkward, and it kind of feels instrumental. Yes, instrumental uses of *cum* also exist, normally when the noun is some kind of tool.

Answer (score 4):

It's an ablative of means: *with the teeth*.

> wolf attacks neck of sheep with teeth